# Convert single array into multidimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

If I have this array in PHP:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "first"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "second"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "third"
}
```

How can I convert this single array into a multidimensional array? What is the quickest way? So I can access this array like:

`$array["first"]["second"]...`

I want to be able to then set a value to this index like:

`$array["first"]["second"]["third"] = "example";`

I thought that I need a for loop or a recursive function but I have no idea how to start.

Comment: Not really clear what the end result should look like. In your example, you've changed the _values_ into the _indexes_. e.g. if you `echo $array["first"]["second"];`, what should it output? What value should be in that field?

Comment: Also...what have you researched or tried so far? We generally prefer to help people with their existing code, rather than just provide the whole solution on a plate. It's better to show you've at least attempted to solve the problem.

Comment: @ADyson Sorry that my question is not clear, I thought that I need a for loop or a recursive function but I have no idea how to start. I have updated my question a little to state how I wish to assign a value to the index.

Comment: Thanks. I can't answer properly now as the question is closed, but here you go: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0d7fa30fde7126160fbcc0e80e5727f17b19e39f . It wasn't quite as simple as I had imagined to begin with. The key to it was doing the process backwards - starting with the last array and then wrapping it in more arrays until you get back to the top level.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you! I would accept your answer if I could.

Comment: Question is back open now, so I added a proper answer for you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't quite as simple as I had imagined to begin with. The key to it was doing the process backwards - starting with the last array and then wrapping it in more arrays until you get back to the top level.

```
$array = array("first", "second", "third");
$newArr = array();

//loop backwards from the last element
for ($i = count($array)-1; $i >= 0 ; $i--)
{
    $arr = array();
    if ($i == count($array)-1) {
        $val = "example";
        $arr[$array[$i]] = $val;
    }
    else { 
        $arr[$array[$i]] = $newArr;
    }
    $newArr = $arr;
}

var_dump($newArr);
echo "-------".PHP_EOL;
echo $newArr["first"]["second"]["third"];
```

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0d7fa30fde7126160fbcc0e80e5727f17b19e39f